# Custom status bar background

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, ios8

I am trying to get a look like this:

[image]

Currently, the status bar adopts the color of the navigation bar. How would I get a sepeate background for the status bar in iOS 8?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put a UIView behind it. The easiest way would be to make a new UIViewController the root view controller that contains your current root view controller. This new root VC would be responsible for positioning and coloring a view behind the status bar. You can get the status bar frame from the app with `statusBarFrame`